# Unable to order my menu by dragging

Tags: menus

I see many have had a similar issue but haven't yet found the answer to my problem specifically.
I am unable to order my Menu through Appearance > Menu and then dragging the items.
I can only order it by going to Pages > Edit and then ordering each page separately.
I plan to have many pages on my website and this method doesn't seem sustainable.
How can I get the dragging method to work? I am using the very common theme Astra and I know for a fact that others using Astra are able to drag their menu into place. Appreciate any help!

Comment: it sounds like there's JS that's broken on that page, open your browser dev tools to find out what the error message is, but keep in mind this is a stack for coders not end users, and you can't ask about 3rd party plugins/themes you downloaded/bought here